# Movie about an African sorceress that turns men into robot-creatures, cured by pulling a splinter out of her back

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've watched this movie back when I was a kid and plot was something this:

The story takes place in black Africa (or some fantasy environment that resembles it). It is about a boy (I believe) in a village, where all the men are abducted by an evil sorceress that turns them into black robot like thingies that do her bidding. As a result there are no men left at the village and they suffer a lot.

The young hero resolves the conflict by pulling a splinter out of the sorceresses back with his teeth, which makes her turn normal again. She reverts all the men to their normal state. The men return in a celebratory procession carrying the hero on their shoulders and chanting something along the line "We are the husbands, we are the sons, we are the uncles, we are the nephews, ..." and so on. I believe that the sorceress was pardoned by the village people *(pun intended)* and that's where the movie ends.

I watched the movie in German, if that's relevant.

Comment: When were you a kid? Was the film new when you watched it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [*Kirikou and the Sorceress*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181627/) (1998)

The plot on Wikipedia seems to match pretty well with your memory, emphasis mine:

> In a little **West African village**, a boy named Kirikou is born in a unusual way. Since he can speak and walk immediately after being born, it's also pretty obvious that he's not a normal baby. After Kirikou's mother tells him that an **evil sorceress** has dried up their spring and devoured all the males of the village except for one, he decides to accompany **the last warrior**, his uncle, to visit her. Kirikou manages to trick the sorceress and save his uncle by waiting inside his uncle's hat and pretending that it's magic. Additionally, he saves the village's children from being kidnapped both by the sorceress' boat and tree, and bursts the monster who was drinking all the village's water. He then travels to ask his wise old grandfather about the sorceress, who tells him that **she is evil because she suffers from a poisoned thorn in her back**. After learning this, Kirikou manages to trick the sorceress and **remove the thorn**, as well as taking the all of her stolen gold and returning it to the rightful owners. The sorceress is cured as a result, and she kisses Kirikou; who then becomes an adult. When they arrive back at the village, no one believes that the sorceress is cured until **a procession of drummers arrive.** Afterwards, the sorceress's watchmen (as well as her other obedient objects) **are turned back into the missing men; revealing that she didn't eat them after all.**
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *Kirikou and the Sorceress*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirikou_and_the_Sorceress)</sub>

You can see the trailer below:

It's also available on YouTube in parts [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pRjTwbm97w).

---

Found by Googling `Movie about an african sorceress that turns men into robot-creatures`, a sub-section of your title.

Comment: Huh, seems I should use google more often. Thanks!